# Flask-socketio: Payload of sent/emit messages not shown in devtools correctly

Tags: python, flask, websocket, google-chrome-devtools, flask-socketio

I just started to play around with websockets in conjuction with Flask. For doing so I decided to use the [`flask-socketio`](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module. The code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send


app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return send_from_directory('html' ,'ws.html')


@socketio.on('connect')
def client_connected():
    # log new messages
    print('client connected')
    send('You are connected. Nice to have you here')


@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    # echo received messages
    print(message)
    send(message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

For the client side I copied a rather ugly `ws.html` (which resides inside a folder called `html`) from the [flask-socketio docs](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#initialization) and updated it to the latest version of socket.io:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.slim.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('message', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
    });
</script>
```

So the overall dir structure is:

```
.
├── srv.py
└── html
    └── ws.html
```

I then had a look at the WebSocket traffic via Chrome's developer tools. However, the output does not seem to be correct. Neither the welcome message upon connect nor the message sent from within the `ws.html` are shown in the frame's payload:

[image: Screenshot of payload in Chrome's dev tools]

In order to narrow things a bit down I installed the npm module [`socketio-debugger`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-debugger). I am not quite sure about its core functionality/usage, but at least flask's welcome message seems to be sent correctly:

```
$ socketio-debugger http://localhost:5000
● start Event › connect
  Connected to http://localhost:5000
❯ log Event › message
  You are connected. Nice to have you here
```

What is going on here? Why do I get incorrect payload in Chrome's dev tools?

Comment: You have omitted a very important detail. Does the `print(message)` statement execute? Or in other words: is the problem that the exchange doesn't work, or that the exchange does work but you don't understand why you don't see it in the dev tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how you phrased your question, I'm going to guess that the test application that you built works correctly, and you are only asking why you don't see the exchange of events in the Chrome dev tools.

The reason is that in the default way of starting a Socket.IO connection, clients connect via long-polling first, and once that connection is established they attempt an upgrade to WebSocket. So always the first few things that are exchanged go through long-polling. If you look at the HTTP requests in your dev tools you will see this event that your client is sending in a `POST` request.

If you want the connection to be established strictly on WebSocket, you can do so from the client as follows:

```
var socket = io.connect(
    'http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port,
    {transports: ['websocket']}
);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle sent messages on client side as well.

When you receive `message` from client side, you can emit some random message again and handle it on client side.

Flask side:

```
@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    # echo received messages
    print(message)
    emit('custom_msg', {'msg': 'hi'})
```

Client side (your *ws.html*)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.slim.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('message', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
    });
    socket.on('custom_msg', function(data){
        console.log(data['msg'])
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code shows that the messages are correctly transferred from client to server and vice versa. However, Chrome dev tools Websocket output for the frame contents is unaffected and still the same.

Comment: I don't want to brag, but I've built something with flask socketio. If you implement websockets correctly, you should see them in frames. http://aukcije-online.herokuapp.com/article/1  ---> This is something I've built, if you open Chrome dev tools and go to frames, and open same article in an other tab, you will see messages. If you want to learn from my project, you can check it here: https://github.com/PinkFrojd/material_aukcije_online .